# Error the FacesContext is already released

Tags: jsf-2, message, facescontext, view-scope

The following code is working with **request scoped** Managed Beans and message is showing in the `p:messages` tag:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

public void addAction() {
    if(commande.exists()) {
                context.addMessage("Commande", new FacesMessage(
                        FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Error Message : commande exists", null));
    } else {
        commandeService.create(commande);
    }
}
```

When I tried to use it in a **view scoped** Managed Bean it gives an error message in the logger:

```
Error the FacesContext is already released!
```

and the JSF page hangs without showing faces message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** assign the current instance of the `FacesContext` or any of its properties as a property of a managed bean. The current instance is only valid in the current HTTP request, it is destroyed by end of the HTTP request and not valid anymore in any subsequent HTTP requests.

You should always get the current instance in the method local scope.

```
public void addAction() {
    if (commande.exists()) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("Commande", new FacesMessage(
            FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error Message : commande exists", null));
    } else {
        commandeService.create(commande);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. with request beans the context property was initialized for each call so the mistake was hidden, but with view scoped beans It's different.